# Dynamic button values from javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a page that does a search, using javascript, and I want to take the list of users that it comes up with, and send that as a submit to the next page. What I have, is:

```
  .search_client_users
    = form_tag admin_clients_path, method: "get" , class: "search_form" do
      = label_tag 'search_term', 'Old domain name:'
      = text_field_tag 'search_term', nil, autocomplete: "off", size: "50"      
    .main_form.client_emails
      = simple_form_for(:domainNameSwap, url: { action: "update" }, html: { method: :put }) do |f|
        .input-row
          = f.hidden_field :users, value: @clients    
        .submit-row
          .row
      .col-xs-5
         .submit
           = f.submit "Update domains", id: "submit", :class => "btn btn-primary submit"
    .client_list

- content_for :javascript do
  = javascript_include_tag 'admin/search_client_users'
```

[some of the formatting may not be quite right due to cut and paste, sorry]

The admin/search_client_users creates an @clients, I'm pretty sure, at least, with:

```
class App.ClientUserList
  constructor: ->
    @incrementalSearchAttempts = 0

  search: (searchTerm, completeCallback) =>
    handleResponseWithOrderAwareness = (attemptNumber, response) =>
      if attemptNumber >= @incrementalSearchAttempts
        completeCallback(response)

    @incrementalSearchAttempts++
    onComplete = _.partial(handleResponseWithOrderAwareness, @incrementalSearchAttempts)
    $.get('/admin/manage_clients/client_list', { search_term: searchTerm }).complete(onComplete)

class App.Views.SearchClientUsers extends Backbone.View
  events:
    "keyup input[name='search_term']": "search",
    "click .profile_attribute": "showClientUserProfile"

  initialize: =>
    @clientUserList = new App.ClientUserList()

  search: =>
    searchTerm = $('.search_form input[name=search_term]').val()
    @clientUserList.search(searchTerm, @render)

  showClientUserProfile: (event) =>
    window.location = $(event.currentTarget).closest('tr').data('client-path')

  render: (response) =>
    @$el.find('.client_list').html(response.responseText)

$ ->
  new App.Views.SearchClientUsers(el: $('.search_client_users')).search()
```

so, I'm trying to take the list of clients, and send it to the update method in the controller. However, due to when javascript and ruby take place, it doesn't seem to be working... is there a way to do this? or do I have to figure out how to do this in Ajax?

ETA: An alternative idea is, I suppose to just turn the initial text_field into a form, so that the text field is used both for the javascript, and THEN submitted to the form, and then the update can re-do the search... My dataset is small enough that doing the search twice is not a huge problem I suppose...

But I'm not quite sure exactly how to merge the two forms...

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Vague problem statement

Comment: @clients is empty. it isn't the list of clients.